# XNA - Process terminates unexpectedly while debugging

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, debugging, xna

I have a curious problem with debugging my XNA project. Whenever I hit a certain breakpoint and start browsing the "Locals" window, the whole process and the debugger terminate without giving any notice as to why. The trigger might be reaching a field with a red exclamation mark that says "Function evaluation was aborted."

I am using no explicit multithreading in my code, therefore I am befuddled how the process can terminate (seemingly as though it correctly reached the end) when it actually doesn't run.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: It sounds as though the attached debugger may be crashing. Is it always on the same breakpoint / method evaluation; or is it seemingly random? Also, what version of Visual Studio are you using (i.e Express, Professional, Ultimate)?

Comment: I'm using VS2010 Ultimate, it is not entirely random, however I think the crash occured on multiple breakpoints. Interesting is, that when I don't browse the Locals and just let the debugger be after hitting the breakpoint, nothing happens.

Comment: It does sound like the debugger itself is crashing when trying to evaluate the locals. I have had a similar issue before and it's not particularly easy to isolate.

Comment: Any chance to at least get some error message from the debugger?

Comment: If the solution you have found works, post it as an answer and accept it so others can identify the solution easily.

Comment: I wil, once the time limit has passed, can't do it yet :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is occurring because your accessor is infinitely recursive, causing a stack overflow.

Change this:

```
get { return Level; }
```

To this:

```
get { return level; }
```

This is actually a fairly common thing in Visual Studio C#, it's very annoying, the auto-complete feature will always prefer the accessor name over the member name, even when you're within the accessor itself. I figured after 5 years of this Microsoft would've fixed it by now.

EDIT: n/m I see you already came to this conclusion in your own question. I guess I should read the entire thing first, I jumped the gun.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have found the solution, so, for anyone who might happen upon this question with a similar problem: The debugger hangs when trying to evaluate a property that causes a stack overflow, i.e

```
protected int level;
    public int Level
    {
        get { return Level; }
    }
```

as is further explained here http://netpl.blogspot.com/2009_05_01_archive.html